# How can I use jQuery Checkboxs to select and then open and/or print documents stored in a content system (html link to get .pdf doc)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I'm a noob to all this and getting stuck!

I have a table that is something like this:

```
<tr class="req">
        <td><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Pform70" /></td>
            <td align="left" ><a     href="https://www.yadayada.com/uat088922.pdf" title="Form Title" id="Pform70" target=new>Pform70</a></td>
    <td>Required</td>
    <td>Form Title </td>
    <td>ksdjasdjf;alsdjfal; </td>
```

So - I want to have a button above the table that will, when clicked, either open all the checked documents or print the checked documents.

I've been searching, come close, but not close enough.   Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the selected (checked) items into a combined .zip file.

First, create a form containing your list of files:

```
<form action="download.php" method="get">
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Download!"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="req">
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="file[0]" id="Pform70" /></td>
  <td align="left"><a href="https://www.yadayada.com/uat088922.pdf" title="Form Title" id="Pform70" target=new>Pform70</a></td>
  <td>Required</td>
  <td>Form Title</td>
  <td>ksdjasdjf;alsdjfal;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Notice the check box name is an array!

Here is the download.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST['file'])) {
    // open zip
    $zip_path = '/path/to/created/download.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive(); 
    if ($zip->open($zip_path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.");
    }  
    // checkbox values dont matter because only checked boxes show up in POST data
    foreach ($_POST['file'] as $key => $val) {
        // generate filename to add to zip
        $filename = '/path/to/php/file' . $key . '.php';
        $zip->addFile($filename) or die ("ERROR: Could not add the file $filename");  
    }
    $zip->close();

    //===============
    // force download
    //===============
// assume you have a full path to file stored in $zip_path
if (!is_file($zip_path)) {
  die('The file appears to be invalid.');
}

$zip_path = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($zip_path));
$filesize = filesize($zip_path);
$filename = substr(strrchr('/'.$zip_path, '/'), 1);
$extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($zip_path, '.'), 1));

// use this unless you want to find the mime type based on extension
$mime = array('application/octet-stream');

header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.sprintf('%d', $filesize));
header('Expires: 0');

// check for IE only headers
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))) {
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
} else {
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
}

$handle = fopen($filepath, 'rb');
fpassthru($handle);
fclose($handle);


} // close $_POST check
```

You can read more about [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) in the php.net docs.